# multpile animation clips in glTF file from blender to a-frame

Tags: aframe, gltf

I've been researching this for 2 days and tried everything I can think of.  How do I make a glTF file with multiple clips in Blender?  I've tried using the action editor then exporting to glTF2.0 with latest Blender glTF 2.0 exporter from Khronos. But I only get one clip. What's the workflow to create separate animation clips for glTF file for a-frame.

Answer (score 2):

The [glTF exporter for blender](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/) now supports multiple animations cf Don's comment. Alternatively you can export to threejs json instead cf e.g. https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/loaders but with other limitations.

Comment: As of 95 hours ago, the glTF Blender exporter has (experimental) support for multiple animations! [Download the version here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/pull/166). I think the three.js JSON format workflow has a lot of issues with multiple animations itself, unfortunately...